# How create a border with a shadow and a transparent fill to let the shadow appear

Tags: css, border, shadow

I am desperately trying to code this Button:

[image: Button]

Could anybody help me? Thanks.

I tried to make a simple button with `box-shadow`, a border and a transparent background but seems impossible.

So you can see in this other codepen that a tried an other approch with an `:after` and `:before` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/tranduy/pen/mMorGp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I've found to do this is to use a pseudo element and apply the blurred border on that.

```
.border-shadow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #F01476;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;

    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      outline: 3px solid #F01476;
      filter: blur(2px);
      transform: translateY(5px);
    }
}
```

If you want a border gradient then you can do something like this:

```
.border-shadow {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;

    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: -3px;
      right: -3px;
      bottom: -3px;
      left: -3px;
      filter: blur(2px);
      transform: translateY(5px);
    }

    &, &:after {
        border-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='50' height='50'><defs><linearGradient id='redgradient'><stop offset='0' stop-color='%23F01476'/><stop offset='1' stop-color='%23F3590F'/></linearGradient></defs><g id='Layer_1'><path d='M0,0 L50,0 L50,50 L0,50 L0,0 z' fill='url(%23redgradient)' width='100%' height='100%'/></g></svg>") 10% stretch;
    }
}
```

[See the jsfiddle for both examples in action](https://jsfiddle.net/7o7r8gp9/3/)

Note: This is unprefixed CSS, so for proper browser support you'll want to apply appropriate prefixes. I advise using [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to handle this for you if possible.

Comment: Very welcome @loan. Feel free to mark this answer as accepted if it does what you want here.

Comment: I cannot do it. My vote is recorded but not displayed because I have less than 15 reputation.  But thanks again !